# Vandalism, spam! What to do?

Tags: discussion, spam

This user has editted my question with nonsense text and put the same text on the answer:
[image]

What to do in this cases?
ps: [the question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/157353/how-to-use-my-themes-bootstrap-features)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Roll back or reject the edit (you did) and flag the answer (you didn't). In this case, the "spam" flag would be appropriate - I've gone ahead and done this for you. I also destroyed the user account responsible for this.

Comment: Oh thanks! That second part I didn't know how to do. Who's able to destroy a new user's account?